# How to batch process images retaining them as PNG in Photoshop?

Tags: photoshop, image-processing, batch, png

I need to optimize 700 images in PNG in a batch process, but Photoshop only gives me the option to optimize the images and export them to JPG, when I want to mantain the images on PNG.
Is there a way to do this on Photoshop or in another tool?
[You can see the screenshot following this link](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/823/screenshot20130104at101.png/).

Answer (score 11):

You can probably do this by creating an action and then batch processing:

Create the action

- with an open file in photoshop
- start recording
- do File > Save As > and set file type to PNG
- or use File > Save for Web if you need to resize or make other modifications
- click Save
- stop recording and save action as "Save As PNG"

(there may also be some built in actions with Photoshop, I can't remember)

Then in Adobe Bridge

- Select all the files you want
- Tools > Photoshop > Batch
- Select your "Save As PNG" action
- Click OK to process

Comment: Make sure you close the file as part of the recording otherwise if it opens too many files Photoshop will give an error and you'll have to force crash it.

Comment: Also note that if you "Save for Web" it *may* store the folder you save in, and later if this folder does not exist the process will fail each time with a "Could not complete the action, since the destination folder does not exist" error.

Comment: Is it possible to perform batch operations without Adobe Bridge?

Answer (score 3):

You want to use ImageMagick, its free and open source.
Get it from http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Then use the "convert" function

To resize a batch of photos, open a terminal window to the folder containing your photos and use the command:
`mogrify -resize 700x700 *.png`

Comment: Does it batch covert?

Comment: This is the best answer, IMHO.  The cost of installing ImageMagick is far outweighed by the simplicity, speed and elasticity of this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Just shift click all of your layers. then right click export as. make sure the layers don't live in folders.

Comment: Shift-click all layers for 700 images?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using "save for Web & Devices"

Some helpful links:

- [The Comprehensive Guide to Saving Images for the Web](http://sixrevisions.com/web_design/comprehensive-guide-saving-images-for-web/)
- (video) [Photoshop Top 40 #34 - Save for Web & Devices](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=prbv_kbvdgQ)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help; I followed the links but I'm having the same issue, because Photoshop only allows me to export the images to JPG, and I don't see the option to export the images to PNG.

Comment: The option should be there in save for web and devices ... top right corner. 

Anyways you can also try the free software GIMP to save images as png. GIMP is free alternative to photoshop.
http://graphicssoft.about.com/od/gimptutorials/tp/save-PNG.htm

Answer (score 0):

1. Create your action
   -In your action you MUST "SAVE AS .png"
2. Go to "Automate > Batch
   -Choose your action, folder, desitination
   -YOU MUST THEN, Check the box "Override Action "Save As" Commands
3. Click "OK" and wallah!  If you saved your action correctly with the "save for web / .png", you will have your image assest outputted properly as .png's
4. NOTE - You will find your outputted folder only on the Desktop, as Windows 8 Photoshop CC folder save location is "FUBAR"

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. However, I don't really see how your answer adds something as it is not different from MikeW's answer posted in January 2013.

Comment: that does not make it wrong. Also Mike advises to use Bridge ... which I had not heard of before.